# How to change the update order while using the SQL UPDATE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, sql-update, primary-key

I have a table where each row is numbered with a unique index(1,2,3,...). 
I want to increase the index of each entry by 4, in order to make space for four new entries at the beginning(indexes 1,2,3 and 4).

I tried using:

```
UPDATE table SET key_index = key_index + 4;
```

But it results in an ERROR because the index must be, as said, unique(increasing 1 by 4 results in 5. Index 5 could already exist).

If I could use the UPDATE statement, starting at the bottom(from highest to lowest index), then there would be such ERROR. Is it possible to use an UPDATE statement like that?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be tricky.  One trick that I use is two updates -- first to a range of values that are "safe".  Second to the desired values:

```
update t
    set key_index = - key_index ;

update t
    set key_index = (- key_index) + 4;
```

You can also drop the unique index/constraint -- or disable it in some databases.

Comment: Thanks! A super simple and effective solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL, you can use a simple `update`, with an `order by` clause that sorts the rows by descending value. This lets you perform the changes in just one query, without any risk of collision (since your values are unique).

MySQL does support `order by` in update statements, and the behavior is [described in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

> If an `UPDATE` statement includes an `ORDER BY` clause, the rows are updated in the order specified by the clause. This can be useful in certain situations that might otherwise result in an error.

The documentation goes on with an example that looks just like your use case.

So:

```
UPDATE table SET key_index = key_index + 4 ORDER BY id DESC;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hY55azPXa5Re48iMHjff8b/1)**:

```
create table mytable (key_index int);
insert into mytable values (1), (4), (5), (8), (9);

update mytable 
set key_index = key_index + 4
order by key_index desc;

select * from mytable;

| key_index |
| --------- |
| 5         |
| 8         |
| 9         |
| 12        |
| 13        |
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon answered it to the point. But if you are updating the key_index, remember to also update the value in the foreign reference tables (if any).

Alternatively, you can try another approach. Add another column say `dup_key_index` with value as `key_index + 4`. Then drop the `key_index` column and rename this new column `dup_key_index` as `key_index` column.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45dce4/1)

```
# Add new column to hold the key_index value
alter table TABLE_NAME add dup_key_index int not null;

# Update this columns value from the key_index value and increment
update TABLE_NAME set dup_key_index = key_index + 4;

# Drop the key_index
alter table TABLE_NAME drop key_index;

# Rename the new column with same name as key_index
alter table TABLE_NAME change dup_key_index key_index int primary key;
```

**SQL Server:**
If you are using SQL Server, the engine takes care of this internally where the following query works:

```
update TABLE_NAME set key_index = key_index + 4;
```

Refer [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50360/95610).